# How to split a full name into two strings without using split method and storing the two strings into two parallel arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, parallel-arrays

So my goal here is to pull the first name and last name from a full name entered into a textbox. I think I have pulled the first name correctly but I am having issues pulling the last. I do not want to use the Split method. Then I am going to store the data into the parallel arrays I have.

```
string name;
name = txtName.Text;
string fullName;
int indexSpace;
indexSpace = name.IndexOf(" ");
string firstName;
firstName = name.Substring(0, indexSpace);
string lastName;
lastName = ????

mFirst[mIndex] = firstName;
mIndex++;
mLast[mIndex] = lastName;
mIndex++;
```

Comment: Side note: you really should think twice about what you actually need... I.e. "Samantha" would be very hard to split into "first" and "last" or something like "Smith, Sam Bob Jr."

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use split? It uses substring indexing under the hood so perf will be negligible. If you're worried about second " " spaces there is an overload whic accepts a count parameter to stop after the first space. Split(char[] separator, int count);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. (Assuming that `name` follows the "firstName lastName" format - without quotes) (Assuming JavaScript or Substring adheres to the [js definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp))

> lastName = name.Substring(indexSpace + 1);

Comment: Ah sorry. This is in c#. Will it be similar?

Comment: Yes, [it appears to behave the same](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx)!